# Running Joomla on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, debugging, joomla

I have joomla running locally on the development environment of Google App Engine, but once I deploy it to GAE I just get this error:

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error
```

- Since google claims that the development server is the identical copy of the production environment, how come joomla is not working on GAE?

I've used a couple of days trying to figure out how to debug this, in order to make joomla work, but I could really use some tips for debugging.

- How do you guys debug in the production environment?
- Any of you got joomla 3.2 running on GAE yet?

cheers!

Comment: Does the configuration.php file exists on the production site and does it ppoint to the same database as the development env?

Comment: The production configuration.php on production points at the cloud sql.like this:
`public $host = "/cloudsql/dbname:instancename"; 

public $user = "root"; 

public $password = 'pass';

public $db = 'dbname';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Read the instructions here: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=828565&p=3114492